# Uploaded debug symbols for Android App Bundle

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, debug-symbols, android-app-bundle

> Warning - This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend that you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug.

This message in Playconsole while releasing a Internal test in .aab (Android Studio)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com........"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 33
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.2"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Gradle -

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

Where should I add

```
android.buildTypes.release.ndk.debugSymbolLevel = { SYMBOL_TABLE | FULL }
```

for Automatic symbol file attachment in .aab ?